# Best practices in keeping users logged in in Unity

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, webserver

My case is specific to Unity, but I imagine this would work for other tools as well. My goal is to have a user sign in once when they download the app and not have to sign in again. I have the code written to establish this connection but I don't know how to authenticate them each time they need to get information about their profile.

As of now I have a Unity C# script that takes in a username and password, it then sends this using UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form); The url will use ssl so it's encrypted and then I have a php script on the webserver at url where it takes the information from a db WHERE username=username then checks the password using verify_password($password, $hash), which the passwords are hashed using pasword_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); Ideally this will be later implemented as auth0 and have 2 factor authentication, but my problem still remains. Once the user has logged in once how do I keep them logged in.

My thoughts on approaching this were once they entered the correct password and the webserver allowed them to log into their account I would store their login info (username and password) in playerprefs in the unity app.

This feels bad and dangerous to me. There shouldn't be any problems since this would just act as if the user had entered their username and password, but the game will do that automatically. This could cause problems if their device gets hacked, or some other app gets access to this data, their password would still be compromised.

My other idea was to have the webserver send them a code which the app would store and use that to login at later times so the user doesn't have to reenter their username or password, and the app doesn't store that information, but I'm not sure if this is 1) secure and 2) what the proper way to go about this is.

This is where I reveal my true ignorance of web development

Am I sending them a login token or cookie to keep them logged in, if so can I really just make up some key for the app to use or is there some standard when it comes to these things, and is there anything else I need to keep in mind when doing this

Answer (score 0):

In the browser we use sessions to keep the user logged in a website. You could do something similar using a authentication key. After login with the username and password, the server returns an unique key that will be used to perform future requests.

Storing the key is similar to storing the username and password, but with they key you can implement restrictions on the server side. The requests using the key may have limited access to the user's account and the key may also be revoked at any time.